# StatisticLaw behind air traffic demand

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, forecasting, econometrics, convergence

I am performing linear regression in order to see the relationship between Air traffic demand, GDP per capita and fares of ticket.

I am interesting in getting elasticities therefore, I used the following specifications:

$ln(PAX)_{t}=int+\beta_{1} .ln(GDPPerCapita)_t+\beta_{2}.ln(Fare)_t+\epsilon_t$

I got signficant result for each estimator. My question is the following: is it relevant to consider Fisher test or student test in such time series regression? 
Does it mean that we consider that air traffic demand has a normal distribution also GDP per capita and fares? The R² is not the more important here?

It does make sense for me to look at p-value in cross sectional data when we study the relationship between size and salary, for instance. Size has a normal distribition also salaries. But I don't see the point of looking at those tests in time series data, as it has nothing to see with normal law or Central Limit Theorem...

Sorry if it is a basic problem, but I think I am applying an empirical strategy without understanding deeply what is it behind.